# Given a functional f, how do you find a v such that f(x) = (x,v)?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I have a functional $f: L^2[-1,1]\to\mathbb{C}$, how do I find a $v$ such that $f(x)=\langle x,v\rangle$ for all $x$? Since $L^2$ is a Hilbert space, I know the Riesz Representation theorem holds but I'm not sure what form $v$ is supposed to take... The functional is

$$
f(x) = i\int_{-1}^{1} x(t) dt + \int_{0}^{1} tx(t)dt
$$

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to end up with is something of the form

$$f(x) = \int_{-1}^1 x(t)\overline{y(t)}\,dt.$$

This is the usual inner product on $L^2([-1,1])$. We can rewrite your expression slightly as

$$f(x) = \int_{-1}^1 i\,x(t)\,dt + \int_{-1}^1 \chi_{[0,1]}(t)t\,x(t)\,dt.$$

Do you see now how to get your $y$?

Comment: Ok great, thanks. I see how to get y but I'm not sure I understand how you rewrote the second term in the expression to change the limits?

Comment: Do you know what the notation $\chi_{[a,b]}$ means?

Comment: No, I have not seen this before.

Comment: Okay then $$\chi_{[a,b]}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x\in[a,b] \\ 0 & x\not\in[a,b]\end{cases}.$$

Comment: You could write it in terms of the Heaviside step function if you're so inclined.

Comment: Oh I see! That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: If my answer has answered your question, please accept the answer so that the question does not go without an accepted answer. Otherwise it will continue to show up in the new question feed.